# Creating SQL Table dynamically (Table designer in Win Form Application)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am creating windows application in .NET. It requires to give facility for designing a table by enduser.

Basically , there will some form in that form there will be grid like we see in SQL Server Management studio. One column for data type(Number,Text etc.. instead of Int,Nvarchar).

Please anybody know how to do it? Anyone knows any open source library of any user control which can help me?

**Edited:**

I also need to give facility for altering table. So it's obvious that exception will be raised if inappropriate modification there.Application will handle it and shows message to end user.

Comment: Only MS SQL Server needed to be supported. Not any other database required as of now.

Comment: You probably will have to write it by yourself - I'm not sure there is a control for that purpose. This does not seem to be an sophisticated task - you'll just have to generate `create table` script based on user input.

Answer (score 2):

How about making your application use [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) SQL/DDL Commands?

Comment: Yes,,We can use it. Reason for asking question is we are working on tight schedule, So if we get any library or usercontrol, then we don't require to give a time for testing and all other stuffs. Otherwise we need to create it from scratch and make it reusable.

Comment: You can either go by this solution or go by @ConradFrix 's solution. Either way, you will have to sweat on this one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to directly using DDL you can use [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx)

Comment: +1 Excellent mention. The amount of work for OP will basically be the same, but it's nice to point an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CREATE TABLE in your script that you create dynamically based on the user's input

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LoginId] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [LocationName] [char](30) NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime]
)
```

Make sure the user you are connecting to the database with has the appropriate permissions to create tables.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you would do is take the data entered by the user, and craft a CREATE TABLE statement as a string that you would pass to a SQLCommand and then call ExecuteNonQuery(). Creating the statement itself is pretty straightforward data parsing; get the value of each cell in your GridView (throw an exception if you don't have all necessary information or it doesn't make sense), and stick it into the command.

I recommend using a StringBuilder to put the string together. You'll likely be using a loop or two to traverse the rows of the gridview when building the column list, in which case simple string concatenation using the "+" operator will be very memory-inefficient (Strings are immutable; they are created and then destroyed, never modified. A new string will be created in memory every time you add one string to another, and the two strings that became the new string will each also be in memory until the GC thread runs, which gives the garbage collector a real workout).